# Firebase Snapshot document data order isn't same all the time

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[Firestore database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxr6g.png)
I'm trying to get a document from Firestore (database image attached) and get a certain key value from the retrieved data. So I have written the following code to do that. I'm getting the data correctly but the iteration order changes every time due to which I'm unable to get the right key value from the JSON object. From the code below sometimes I get coins value at data[0], sometimes I get gems value at data[0] and sometimes other one's value at that place. so its causing issue getting the right key-value pair.

```
export const playRoulette = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) 
=> {
  const promise = admin
    .firestore()
    .doc("cashon/G0eebNKdpNR9vsig96nB3eKyVqg1")
    .get();

  const p2 = promise.then(snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.data();

    if (data) {
      const gemsKey = Object.keys(data)[0];
      const gemsValue = Object.values(data)[0];

      response.send(gemsKey + " : " + gemsValue);
    }
  });

  p2.catch(error => {
    response.status(500).send("Error getting documents: " + error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you give more info on what you exactly want to get with `gemsKey` (the string "gems" or the value 45000?) and with `gemsValue`  (the string "coins" or the value 35000?). In other words, what should be the exact result of `gemsKey + " : " + gemsValue`

Comment: With gemsValue, I was trying to get the value of field gems that is 45000. but in data snapshots, the values are shifting their positions. Sometimes at data[0] I get the values of gems sometimes at data[o] I get the values of coins.

Comment: Ok, it is clear for `gemsValue` but what do you want for `gemsKey`? Just "gems"? again, what should be the exact result of `gemsKey + " : " + gemsValue`? `gems : 45000` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly that the value of `gemsKey + " : " + gemsValue` shall be `gems : 45000` (based on your screenshot), you should do as follows:

```
export const playRoulette = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .doc("cashon/G0eebNKdpNR9vsig96nB3eKyVqg1")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {

            const data = snapshot.data();
            const gemsValue = data.gems;

            response.send( { "gems : " + gemsValue });

        } else {
           // snapshot.data() will be undefined in this case
           throw new Error("Document does not exist");
        }
   })
   .catch(error => {
         response.status(500).send("Error getting documents: " + error);
   });

});
```